# Would a solar flare hitting the earth cause rainfall?

Tags: science-based, planets, water, flare-stars, waterfall

- If you have hydrogen gas, oxygen gas and heat together, it will trigger an (exotermic) reaction that produces water.
- Earths atmosphere consists of around 21% oxygen.
- Our sun is made mostly out of hydrogen, meaning a solar flare is probably made mostly out of hydrogen.

From these observations, it seems logical that at least some water would be produced if a bunch of hot hydrogen from a solar flare crashed into our oxygen-rich atmosphere.

Would it be enough water to cause rainfall? And if so, how much would it rain?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a question about building a fictional world. You're asking about the effect of real world phenomena in what is presumably the real world.

Comment: @sphennings "Worldbuilding Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for writers, artists and others using science, geography and culture to construct imaginary worlds and settings." - I would say my question fits this site as a science-based imaginary setting.

Comment: As written you haven't demonstrated that you're building a fictional world. It's a pretty low bar but as written you've failed to clear it. You're just asking about the effects of a common stellar phenomena on the upper atmosphere. An interesting question but currently not one suitable for this site.

Comment: Hi Tobias. Thanks for asking your question. While [we do permit Real World questions on this stack](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6161/40609), they are expected to involve a worldbuilding context to meet the expectations of our [help/on-topic], which states, "Worldbuilding Stack Exchange is a site for designers, writers, artists, gamers and enthusiasts to get help creating imaginary worlds." This would be a good question for [astronomy.se], [chemistry.se], or [physics.se]. (\*continued\*)

Comment: But I will give you two hints: (1) [if you heat water enough, the oxygen and hydrogen molecules break apart, further fueling the fire](https://firefighterinsider.com/water-flammable/). And (2), the [hydrogen in a star isn't burning in the way you're talking about, and it's not near the surface](https://starchild.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/StarChild/universe_level2/stars.html). If you think those two hints through, you'll have your answer.

Comment: Answered below because I think solar flares are dramatic and could be a good story element in world building. I t would be nice if the question was frames with a world building context. The idea of space weather is pretty well established but how space weather impacts real weather seems more open except for Aurora    Borealis.

Comment:  I literally can't stop laughing at this question.

Comment: Ok, now seriously, the OP should atleast consider that the solar flares are too diffuse to actually generate much water

Answer (score 3):

> On [January 20th, 2005](https://www.nasa.gov/vision/space/livinginspace/27jan_solarflares.html), a giant sunspot named "NOAA 720" exploded. The blast sparked an X-class solar flare, the most powerful kind, and hurled a billion-ton cloud of electrified gas (a "coronal mass ejection") into space. Solar protons accelerated to nearly light speed by the explosion reached the Earth-Moon system minutes after the flare--the beginning of a days-long "proton storm."

A Hydrogen atom is a proton with an electron, so in a solar flare or mass ejection you do get a lot of protons (ionized hydrogen) potentially hitting the earth. You also have a lot of electrons ejected and overall the solar flare is charge neutral.  You can also get cosmic rays (not from the sun)- a lot are protons at very very high velocities.

And yes, in the upper atmosphere you have a lot of very reactive atomic oxygen, ozone etc.

However,  I think with the magnetic field protecting the earth is one factor to consider, if you look at the Van Allen belts you will see the inner one is dominated by electrons, and the another farther from the earth is protons and ions.  So that helps keep the protons away from the upper atmosphere.  But for a big event, if protons are entering the atmosphere they would first become atomic hydrogen when they got an electron and would react with what could be available, but in the upper atmosphere they could be come ionized again. Same with the atomic oxygen in the upper atmosphere low earth orbit, both would be bombarded by UV from the sun, other energetic particles etc. So it can be somewhat complicated. Through diffusion, perhaps some small number of the protons from the sun might ultimately make it down deeper in the atmosphere, and some might get kicked out into space by another energetic particle.

The other issue with making it rain, is that you need to have some amount of humidity, and that becomes hard to define in the upper atmosphere, you also usually want to have a nucleating particle for the rain drop to form around.  In a cloud chamber you can see the path of a charge particle as it helps nucleate droplets, but that is becasue of the very high humidity and being near saturation. So if you had a bunch of the solar protons hitting an area of high humidity near saturation perhaps it could help seed rain, but since the magnetic field is protecting the earth, usually the particles that get closest to the ground are near the poles, and it is pretty dry near the poles since it colder.

So I would guess it would be hard for a solar storm to kick off a rain storm, and the amount of hydrogen that really gets into the atmosphere is also pretty small too. I don't know of any correlation between solar storms and rain.... so I would guess no.

If you are interested in solar flares etc. The NOAA Space weather page is [here](https://www.swpc.noaa.gov/)

Answer (score 2):

Answer to main question

### No

According to wikipedia :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_flare

Solar flare isn't sun throwing it's component outward, it Electromagnetic Radiation.
which have very low effect/connection to rainfall
if you read in Effects section, Solar flare is absorbed by earth's atmosphere, don't reach earth's surface, mess up radio/signal stuff due to ionization and increased atmosphere's temperature a bit (which probably wont aid cloud condensation for sure)

But if you insist, it would still be impossible due to how stuff in space worked

-If the sun actually expel hydrogen from itself, said hydrogen will disperse away in vacuum space before reaching earth.

-If still insist that said hydrogen froze into hydrogen chuck (and/or form into others solid state with w/e element), it still really unlikely that said chuck would make itself to earth (given 151 million km, and said solar flare need to line up with earth orbit as well)

So if you really want something that affect your planet's weather. Your best bet is earth with ring composed out of hydrogen chucks, close enough to provide extra hydrogen source to planet's atmosphere and form extra water.

Now we can move on to next question,

**"how much extra water need (or in this place, Hydrogen) to make a rainfall?"**

thank to google that i don't have to do the math

[1 kg of Hydrogen can make 2.38 gallons water](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1748-9326/2/3/034007/pdf)(assumed no lost,we have plenty of oxygen + assumed that heat from asteroid entering atmosphere is enough for the conversion )

and
you need about [17.4 million gallons of water to form 1 mile² of thunderstorm cloud](https://wxguys.ssec.wisc.edu/2011/09/12/how-much-condensed-liquid-water-is-in-a-cubic-mile-of-fog/)

simple math 17.4 million / 2.38 = 7.3 million kg of hydrogen needed [7,300 tons]

in conclusion, you need to throw about 8,000 tons of hydrogen (in form of asteroid, [would be around 4-5 m in diameter](https://www.real-world-physics-problems.com/asteroid-impact.html) or bigger depend on if it pure hydrogen or hydrogen formed with other element in solid state) at your planet to get a thunder storm

Comment: oh.... or just throw ice asteroid instead, that worked too

Comment: Well, no. An ice asteroid wouldn't evaporate before it hit the ground, so it wouldn't be rainfall. It would vaporize on contact (like the Tunguska event), thus distributing heated water into the local atmosphere, but it would be a long time before that were converted to rain. There's really no mechanism for making rain from space. There's too much stuff in the way.